# Return bad request for all calls made over http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, http-redirect

I'm trying to figure out how can I return a bad request when a call is made over HTTP connection as oppose to https. The only way I could figure out how to do this is to write a middleware and inspect each request in the following manner:

```
public class HttpRequestInterceptor
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public HttpRequestInterceptor(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var scheme = context.Request.Scheme;
        if (scheme.Equals("http", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("{\"result:\" \"Bad Request\"}", Encoding.UTF8);
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a built-in way via the framework?

Comment: Why don't you use `UseHttpsRedirection()` middleware instead ?

Comment: @MoienTajik the way I understand how that function works is, it will redirect the page from http to https. While this is good for websites, for API's best practice is either to not listen on http or to return a bad request to ensure man in the middle attack cannot occur. I'm choosing to return a bad request. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter like [this](https://github.com/nbarbettini/ApiSecurity/blob/master/ApiSecurity/RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute.cs) by deriving from RequireHttpsAttribute:

```
/// <summary>
/// An authorization filter that closes connections if they are not secure (HTTPS).
/// Be aware that sensitive information sent by the client WILL be visible!
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    protected int StatusCode { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a status result with the given status code when the request does not use HTTPS.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode"></param>
    public RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute(int statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a 400 Bad Request status code result when the request does not use HTTPS.
    /// </summary>
    public RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute()
     : this(400)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the status result to the appropriate StatusCodeResult specified in the constructor.
    /// The default is 400 Bad Request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCode);
    }
}
```

And then you can register it globally in your application:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    opt.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute())
});
```